# ECharts - decimal data plotted as two seperate data points

Tags: echarts

I'm drawing a scatter plot with data like this:

```
myData = ['Exp 123','false','6','135','1.75'];
```

I have multiple series, so I put the last number, 1.75, into its own variable:

```
var z = myData[4];
```

But when I try to plot that single number (1.75):

```
series: [{ type: scatter, data: z }]
```

It is parsed as an array and comes out as two separate data points: 1 and 75

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you are doing this and what result you expect, but the documentation indicates that an [array is expected](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-scatter.data) as an input. Pay attention that expect array of integer but not strings.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps it will be clearer if you post a working code.

Comment: May be you need to add this data to Axis?

Comment: Thanks Sergey. The reason is I'm plotting a line of historic data (experimental IC50 values, let's say) and comparing the most recent IC50 (one value) as a scatter plot on top of the historic line chart. This will show how the most recent data point compares to the trend line of historic data. Is there a better way (than scatter) to lot a single point?

Comment: I think I understand (and became a medical chemist while reading about the IC50 hehe)) what you need to get. You want to show how IC50 is derived on time? Like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Example_IC50_curve_demonstrating_visually_how_IC50_is_derived.png)? [This official example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=scatter-exponential-regression) similar to desired chart?

Comment: Right. How does the value change over time [like this](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/32-r-graphics-essentials/128-plot-time-series-data-using-ggplot/#add-trend-smoothed-line). 
I have it working now. Thanks for your help and pointer to the API. Now I have to figure out how to order dates on my x axis :)

Comment: Great! You can try to use two (and more) xAxis one above the other. `xAxis: [{bla1},{bla2}]`